# AD authentication in ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I have an ASP.net application with a 'Login' page which authenticates a user against AD. I am using 'Anonymous' authentication for this website and hosting on IIS 7.5.  I want to modify it so that when the user clicks on the icon to go to this website(the icon sits on another website), if the user in the "office network", my website should not ask for his credentials. If the user is not within the network, the 'Login' page should load. Can someone help achieve this?

I tried using the following Session_Start but didn't work:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("LogonPage.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: any possibility of checking the IP address of incoming request and deciding on the basis of that.

Comment: will checking IP address work if the user is logged-in using VPN?

Comment: logged into office network through VPNor to some third party VPN network?

Comment: sorry,I meant logged into office network through VPN